# How to remove backslash from decoded JSON string?

Tags: python, json, base64

I have records that have a list of maps(dict). in which I have encoded data in it.
when we decode the data we get a JSON string with extra backslashes.
Now I need to remove the backslashes '' from the JSON string.

```
{"records": [{'data': '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', 'result': 'Ok', 'recordId': '12345'}]}
```

JSON output (rawdata), after decoded data.

```
"{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\\\"eventVersion\\\":\\\"1.04\\\",\\\"userIdentity\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Root\\\"}\"}\n\n{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\\\"eventVersion\\\":\\\"1.05\\\",\\\"userIdentity\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Root\\\"}\"}\n\n{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\\\"eventVersion\\\":\\\"1.06\\\",\\\"userIdentity\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Root\\\"}\"}\n\n"
```

my python program:

```
import base64

for r in records
    SRC=r["data"]
    rawdata = base64.b64decode(SRC).decode('utf-8')
    Data = rawdata.replace('\\', '')
    removenewline = Data.replease('\n', '')
    mydata = removenewline.replace("\'", '"')
    
return mydata
```

but this is able to remove double backslashes and newline (\n), but it leaves single backslashes.
output:

```
"{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\"eventVersion\":\"1.04\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"Root\"}\"}{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\"eventVersion\":\"1.05\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"Root\"}\"}{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\": \"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role\",\"source\": \"ptfe_atlas_log_events\",\"sourcetype\":\"aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas\",\"instance_id\":\"123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1\",\"log_file\":\"CloudTrail\",\"event\": \"{\"eventVersion\":\"1.06\",\"userIdentity\":{\"type\":\"Root\"}\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Those backslashes look like properly escaped quotes from deeper JSON strings. Removing them would create invalid JSON strings.

Seems you have multiple JSON strings in that base64 string. And each JSON object has an "event" item that's another JSON string with a missing "}".

```
import json, base64

data = {"records": [{'data': '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', 'result': 'Ok', 'recordId': '12345'}]}

for record in data["records"]:
    raw_data = base64.b64decode(record["data"]) # decode base64 string
    raw_data = raw_data.split(b"\n") # split multiple JSON strings
    record["data"] = [json.loads(s) for s in raw_data if s] # parse each JSON string and ignore empty strings
    for rd in record["data"]:
        rd["event"] = json.loads(rd["event"]+"}") # add the missing "}" and parse the JSON string
        
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

This gets you:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "time": 1432826855000,
                    "host": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role",
                    "source": "ptfe_atlas_log_events",
                    "sourcetype": "aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas",
                    "instance_id": "123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1",
                    "log_file": "CloudTrail",
                    "event": {
                        "eventVersion": "1.04",
                        "userIdentity": {
                            "type": "Root"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time": 1432826855000,
                    "host": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role",
                    "source": "ptfe_atlas_log_events",
                    "sourcetype": "aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas",
                    "instance_id": "123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1",
                    "log_file": "CloudTrail",
                    "event": {
                        "eventVersion": "1.05",
                        "userIdentity": {
                            "type": "Root"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "time": 1432826855000,
                    "host": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FirehosetoS3Role",
                    "source": "ptfe_atlas_log_events",
                    "sourcetype": "aws:cloudwatchlogs:ptfe_atlas",
                    "instance_id": "123456789012_CloudTrail_us-east-1",
                    "log_file": "CloudTrail",
                    "event": {
                        "eventVersion": "1.06",
                        "userIdentity": {
                            "type": "Root"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "result": "Ok",
            "recordId": "12345"
        }
    ]
}
```